# Small Cloud Database

Tags: database-recommendation

I'm researching the best way to do the following but haven't been able to come up with anything.  I'm trying to build a small (probably 3 or so tables with at most 200 records each) relational database that is hosted online.  If it could be hosted offline, I'd use Access and call it a day, but I can't figure out an equivalent that is online.

Requirements are:

- accessible online via anywhere
- ability to restrict viewing of certain information to certain users
- once setup, is very easy to use

Preferable:

- not a lot of coding - I'm not fluent in any server side coding and don't want to spend the time learning for this small of a project - e.g. Access can do a lot without coding
- free though cheap is an option (since this is a small project, it shouldn't cost more than 5-10$ a month)

If this isn't possible, I'd be obliged if someone could direct me to the closest thing to it. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to strictly access the data stored within your tables, you could just create a public, Google spreadsheet.  This isn't a database, but it will allow you to share/access your database from the web.  However, if you want to create these tables and want to consume this information in GUI (i.e. some form of formatted table or a web form), you will need an online, DB solution.  There are many options and, unfortunately, we would need to know a little bit more about your project to make a good recommendation.

Comment: What specifically do you need to know about the project?  Part of the problem I'm having is that I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: You've mentioned that you want to have cloud-access (i.e. data available from the internet) but you haven't explained your intent.  Is this back-end data, used to populate an interface?  Is this just reference material?  I know you are not a coder, but will you need to implement an interface that calculates other data-points and displays the derived information, rather than the underlying data in the tables?  There are many uses for "just a few tables".  Understanding the point of this project can go a long way in helping you solve your problem.  That's all I'm asking.

Comment: Here is another question that might help.  What's wrong with the Google Spreadsheet option?  What additional functionality do you need beyond that?

Comment: You know, I think Google Spreadsheets with a web interface front-end might work.  I wasn't sure whether I had access to the web interface, but it turns out I do so that will work.  Would you like to create an answer with Google Spreadsheets and I'll accept it?

Comment: I posted an answer just as you've requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are needing simple access to tabular data, from the web, then [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/) has a spreadsheet document option which should suffice.  Granted, this isn't a database but it's easy to use and does not involve any coding.

Also, Google Docs are stored on your "Google Drive".  Therefore you will need to have a Google account and you may have to accept a series of terms and conditions for multiple accounts before you can begin using Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 2):

If you are strictly interesting in

- setting up a quick-and-dirty database
- free to use and setup
- not worrying about a lot of administration
- not being tied down to Storage Engine configuration/tuning specifics

then I would recommend the [**Xeround Cloud Database service**](http://xeround.com/).

[I just wrote a post about Xeround's limitations in terms of MySQL and its configurability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/what-is-the-best-and-most-performant-mysql-cloud-solution/31380#31380). Since that is not a concern, Xeround gives you a fairly easy Database to setup and tools to manage it. You can literally create a Xeround MySQL Instance in under 5 minutes.

The free service will give you room to create a 10MB DB. If you need slightly more space, [there are pricing options](http://xeround.com/mysql-cloud-db-overview/pricing/).

Comment: I think a database is going to end up being too complicated for my needs.  A simple series of Google Spreadsheets with a web front-end is going to be easier.  Thanks though.  I'll keep this in mind for any future projects.